# How to insert foreign key in sequelize model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a User model and a Houses model in sequelize. I also have a UserHouse model that contains {user_id, house_id}. How do I populate values in the UserHouse model.

I went through the sequelize documentation but could not get a clear idea.
I need to know, how to insert user_id and house_id in UserHouse model.

I also cannot understand what associations should I use between these models.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edited**:

**One More issue:**
 I have one more model HouseInfo that stores house_id (foreign key),
how should I store this "house_id" foreign key in db and how should I associate the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.belongsToMany(House, { through: UserHouse });
House.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserHouse });

user.addHouse(house);
house.setUsers([user1, user2])
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/

Comment: thankyou, will definitely use this. I have one more situation, what should I do in this case:  HouseInfo model that stores house_id (foreign key)?